# DHCP Requests not coming through

Tags: cisco, vlan, dhcp

I've currently got a network issue that is preventing clients connecting to a guest WiFi network from getting an IP address via DHCP. I've been re-configuring and tweaking setting for the last few days - but I am sure from the details below it is a simple problem. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

**The port config is as follows:**

```
Wireless Controller Port 2, Guest_Vlan Interface ---> Connects to ---> Switch 1 Port 25  - Trunk VLAN 50

Switch 1 Port 1- Trunk VLAN 50  ---> Connects to ---> ASA GigabitE Port 3 ( 192.168.50.1 ) - Which is configured for VLAN 50 as well.
```

The only other thing I can think of, is the IP settings on the Interface on the Wireless Controller are possibly wrong...

```
Wireless Controller Port 2:

VLAN Identifier 50
IP Address 192.168.50.5
Netmask 255.255.255.0
Gateway 192.168.50.1

DHCP Information     
Primary DHCP Server - 192.168.50.1
```

**ASA Configuration**

GigabitEthernet0/3

```
Interface GigabitEthernet0/3 "guest", is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is i82574L rev00, BW 1000 Mbps, DLY 10 usec
        Auto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(100 Mbps)
        Input flow control is unsupported, output flow control is off
        MAC address 24e9.b392.2656, MTU 1500
        IP address 192.168.50.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.0
        137460 packets input, 30292652 bytes, 0 no buffer
        Received 112409 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants
        0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
        0 pause input, 0 resume input
        14684 L2 decode drops
        130493 packets output, 50799818 bytes, 0 underruns
        0 pause output, 0 resume output
        0 output errors, 0 collisions, 13 interface resets
        0 late collisions, 0 deferred
        0 input reset drops, 0 output reset drops
        input queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (468/390)
        output queue (blocks free curr/low): hardware (490/445)
```

**DHCP Pool**

```
dhcpd address 192.168.50.150-192.168.50.200 guest
dhcpd enable guest
```

Comment: Can you ping from the wireless controller to the ASA (or vice versa)?  Please include the ASA config (sanitized)

Comment: I cannot ping the ASA from the controller :(

Comment: Make sure you allow pings on the ASA.  But if it still doesn't work, the problem might be in the interface configuration on the ASA or switch.  If you post them, we can help you.

Comment: Pings are allowed - I can ping when connected on the other SSID that is on a different VLAN. The configs are exactly the same, just different IP ranges and VLAN Ids

Comment: As I said, the problem is likely on the ASA interface config or the switch config.  But without seeing them, I'm just guessing.

Comment: Like Ron said. You state that the interfaces are configured for VLAN50 but you don't show the actual config. Please add the running config of all the relevant interfaces and the output of a "show vlan" on the switch.

Comment: Are you able to get a DHCP address with a computer if it is plugged in on another another switchport on vlan 50? If so, it points to something on the Wireless Controller. Assuming you are using a Cisco WLC, check on the WLC how you're handling DHCP (DHCP proxy or DHCP Bridging). Edit: If you are trunking to the ASA and trunking to the Wireless Controller, are you setting the vlan tag? Or are you using native vlan 50?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the requested (sanitized) configurations. Speculation and guessing is off-topic here, and we cannot help you without more information.

Comment: @pac_man - thanks, from your comment I found that the tagging was setup incorrect on the switchport that the WLC was connected too! I've now resolved the issue. Thanks!